# Send Results To Different List with Regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

So here is my example code:

```
import re
results = []
ex = re.match('ab', 'ab')
ex.group()
```

And my result:

```
'ab'
```

How do I send the results that were kept by `ex.group` into the my `results` list? I am a newbie with regex by the way.

Comment: `results.append(ex.group())` ?

Comment: Your pattern doesn't contain any capture groups. Which group(s) are you referring to? The entire match?

Comment: The group is the entire match, which is the result of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `results.append(ex.group())`.